# Pandas dataframe concatenation in for loop resulting in empty dataframes

Tags: python, pandas

I am sure that I am missing something obvious. The concatenation works because "print d" prints exactly what I want, but for some reason it doesn't stick outside of the for loop. If I ask to print one of the dataframes outside the loop, they are all empty dataframes. Please help.

```
file_name = ['anal_cc_cbs/ld-non_aug-atqd', 'anal_cc_cbs/ld-non_aug-tqt', 'anal_cc_cbs/ld-non_aug-q5t', 
        'anal_cc_cbs/ld-atqd', 'anal_cc_cbs/ld-tqt', 'anal_cc_cbs/ld-q5t', 'anal_fnocc_cbs/ld-non-aug-atqd', 
        'anal_fnocc_cbs/ld-non-aug-tqt', 'anal_fnocc_cbs/ld-non-aug-q5t', 'anal_fnocc_cbs/ld-atqd', 
        'anal_fnocc_cbs/ld-tqt', 'anal_fnocc_cbs/ld-q5t', 'anal_fnocc_cbs/ld-56t', 'vdz_rad', 'vtz_rad', 'vqz_rad',
        'v5z_rad', 'avdz_rad', 'avtz_rad', 'avqz_rad', 'av5z_rad', 'vdz-f12_rad', 'vtz-f12_rad', 'tzvpp_rad',
        'qzvpp_rad']

o_tqd_df=pd.DataFrame(); o_tqt_df=pd.DataFrame(); o_q5t_df=pd.DataFrame(); 
o_atqd_df=pd.DataFrame(); 
o_atqt_df=pd.DataFrame(); o_aq5t_df=pd.DataFrame(); o_ftqd_df=pd.DataFrame(); 
o_ftqt_df=pd.DataFrame(); 
o_fq5t_df=pd.DataFrame(); o_fatqd_df=pd.DataFrame(); 
o_fatqt_df=pd.DataFrame(); o_faq5t_df=pd.DataFrame(); 
o_fa56t_df=pd.DataFrame(); o_vdz_df=pd.DataFrame(); o_vtz_df=pd.DataFrame(); 
o_vqz_df=pd.DataFrame(); 
o_v5z_df=pd.DataFrame(); o_avdz_df=pd.DataFrame(); o_avtz_df=pd.DataFrame(); 
o_avqz_df=pd.DataFrame();
o_av5z_df=pd.DataFrame(); o_vdz_f12_df=pd.DataFrame(); 
o_vtz_f12_df=pd.DataFrame(); o_tzvpp_df=pd.DataFrame(); 
o_qzvpp_df=pd.DataFrame() 

df_name = [o_tqd_df, o_tqt_df, o_q5t_df, o_atqd_df, o_atqt_df, o_aq5t_df, 
o_ftqd_df, o_ftqt_df, o_fq5t_df, o_fatqd_df,
      o_fatqt_df, o_faq5t_df, o_fa56t_df, o_vdz_df, o_vtz_df, o_vqz_df, 
o_v5z_df, o_avdz_df, o_avtz_df, o_avqz_df,
      o_av5z_df, o_vdz_f12_df, o_vtz_f12_df, o_tzvpp_df, o_qzvpp_df]

for f, d in zip(file_name, df_name):
    allFiles = glob.glob('/theoryfs2/ds/warden/projects/fp_opt/' + f + '/ld-*')
    dlist = []
    for fil in allFiles:
        df = pd.read_csv(fil)
        dlist.append(df)
    d = pd.concat(dlist)
    print d
```

Comment: FYI, Panel is depreciated as of 0.20.0 (https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/dsintro.html#panel)

Comment: OP, you should use a dictionary not this. I have no clue whats going on and a dictionary would be much more simple. `file_name: pd.DataFrame`

Comment: @tywoodpav Awww, just when I was about to use them. Thanks, I didn't know that. So...will they rename pandas too? ;) (deleting my earlier comment)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
from collections import defaultdict    

dfs = defaultdict(pd.DataFrame)

for filename in filenames:
    with open(filename) as list_of_csvs:
        for csv_file in list_of_csvs:
            dfs[filename].append(pd.read_csv(csv_file))
```

I have no idea what those files are. I am assuming they are text files with lines to csv files.

This code creates a dictionary of dataframes where each dataframe has the accumulated contents of the CSV files listed in the file.

EDIT: Worth mentioning that `defaultdict` creates a dictionary but you dont have to do `if key not in d: d[key] = pd.DataFrame()`. Very handy trick you should use whenever possible.

Comment: Thank you. This worked. They were folders of csv files that I was trying to append to separate dataframes for each folder.